# Can I get a Lead View to show converted Leads?

Tags: apex, rest-api, metadata-api, leads, list-view

I am using apex code to give me all of the leads in a lead view like this:

```
Database.QueryLocator ql = Database.getQueryLocator('select Id from Lead limit 1');
ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(ql);

setController.setFilterID(RestContext.request.params.get('filter'));
setController.getRecords();
```

It seems the way that Lead Views work you can only have them return unconverted leads, but I want to look at leads that match the various filters of a Lead View and have been converted. The only way I have found that might allow me to do this would be to use the Metadata API which seems to give me access to the individual filters of a Lead View (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm)

If I had the individual filter parameters, I could then generate an SOQL query which could return me converted leads, but I am hoping there is an easier way. Is it possible to get the filters of a Lead View from apex?

If I do need to use the metadata api, can I authenticate with it using the credentials I get from the signed request I get as a Canvas App? (currently my app just uses the REST API with a couple custom apex rest endpoints)  I found a Ruby gem that supposedly talks to the metadata API (https://github.com/ejholmes/metaforce) but It asks for a username, password, and security_token.  Is it not possible to use this API in a way that it can be packaged up and deployed to someone else's organization without them giving you their username password and whatever a security token is?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be an easier way of doing this.

Comment: I want to do some analysis of the conversions of leads in a given lead view, so basically I want "select count(Id) from Lead where ConvertedOpportunityId != NULL and ConvertedDate >= start_date and ConvertedDate < end_date and THE LEAD WAS IN SOME LEAD VIEW"

Comment: The term "analysis" makes me think this might be better as a report. There are out of the box reports for this. "Campaigns with Leads and Converted Leads Information" shows a list with the converted data next to the leads.

Comment: Is there any way to run these types of reports and get the results via an API? I'm writing an application that needs to get this data and present it to users, I'm not just trying to get it for my own organization